# Photo sent by telegram bot from Google Drive is cropped

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot

I created a Telegram bot to send photos (currently in .jpg file type) to different commands. I'm using Google Apps Script because my photos are stored in my Google Drive and I thought it be a good idea to use a Sheet to keep track of my photos and their urls.

However, the photos that are being sent by the bot are cropped. I read through the API and didn't find anything specifying the dimensions of the photos needed. Could someone please shed light on this? How can I prevent Telegram from cropping my photos? Or, is that a preferred size that my photos should be so that it wouldn't be cropped?

More Information:
I saved my photos in a google drive folder and manually created a sharing link and save them in my spreadsheet. Suppose I have a photo url in cell A1 of ActiveSpreadsheet, my code looks like this

```
  photo_url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
  sendPhoto(chatID,photo_url)

   function sendPhoto(id,photo_url) {
   var API_TOKEN = my_API_token;
   var payload = {
          'method': 'sendPhoto',
          'chat_id': String(id),
          'photo': photo_url,
        }

        var data = {
          "method": "post",
          "payload": payload
        }
   UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + API_TOKEN + '/', data);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the snippet of the code you are using to do this? And how are you passing the photo from the Drive to the Bot?

Comment: @ADW I have added the main part of the source code that invokes the sendPhoto method from the api. The photos I have are all in the size 320x225. I will do some tests later with photos of different sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful with the format of the `photo_url`.

You may be using the url generated by the `getUrl()` method:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_ID
```

This will send a cropped image.

---

On the other hand, using the following url will send an untruncated image:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_ID
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. It didn't work at first but then I replaced 'docs' with 'drive' and it now works. Thank you! May I ask how I can find out information like this on my own? Is there a documentation that I could read up or is it simply a know-how that I needed to pick up by myself?

Comment: Well, this specific issue took me some time to figure out. Am working on a project that uses Telegram, FireStore and Google Apps Script. The edges/connections are where the documentation isn't helpful/enough. If you are working on something similar, try [my github](https://github.com/amitwilson/GoogleAppsScript) or just ping me on [twitter](https://twitter.com/amit_wilson). I have a bunch of snippets I reuse.